# Can we record screen video of android devices?

Tags: android

Is their any source code or sample project which allows to record video of the running screen of application.
I have to make an application which has ability to record video of the application screen in android devices.
I search about this, but haven't find anything.

Comment: We can do so in rooted device only

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424149/capture-android-screen-and-create-video-programatically

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia What about this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800030/how-to-record-android-screen-video-programmatically-in-kitkat-4-4

Comment: Haven't you seen API supported version , its 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I have developed it.

For that you have to make background service and programmatically capture screenshot on every second and after that combine all images and make video using FFMPEG.

I hope it will work for you.

Let me know if you need more help in same.

Comment: But this way you can take snap shot of parent view of that activity not of screen, you will not able to see status bar, any dialog etc.

Comment: Yes for that in service make transparent view before 2 seconds on capture and remove view after 5 seconds of capture.

Comment: @Vatsal Shah Thanks, Can you please share some code with me to perform such task, as i am a beginner in android.

Comment: Please check my post to make video from images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073336/how-to-combine-images-and-generate-a-mp4-file/31073888#31073888

Comment: @VatsalShah thanks Vatsal, Let me checkout this link, Let me inform you if need your help

Comment: @AmitSaini Sure you can msg me.